# Node-Red and Web socket

Tags: window, node-red

I'm trying to works on node-red's websockets on windows environment (I've successfully try on Linux).

I've simple apps like pictured below

[image: node red - actual deployed node]

and it's doesn't work output on console :

```
17 Feb 09:07:04 - [error] [websocket out:c87881cc.37878] TypeError: Cannot read property 'wholemsg' of null
```

node-red json :

```
[{
    "id": "50702139.8696e",
    "type": "websocket-client",
    "z": "f00fcb86.2de8f8",
    "path": "/press",
    "wholemsg": "false"
}, {
    "id": "c87881cc.37878",
    "type": "websocket out",
    "z": "f00fcb86.2de8f8",
    "name": "",
    "server": "",
    "client": "50702139.8696e",
    "x": 361,
    "y": 66,
    "wires": []
}, {
    "id": "c99314fe.366ce8",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "f00fcb86.2de8f8",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 163,
    "y": 67,
    "wires": [["c87881cc.37878"]]
}, {
    "id": "12f91072.ed06f",
    "type": "websocket in",
    "z": "f00fcb86.2de8f8",
    "name": "",
    "server": "",
    "client": "50702139.8696e",
    "x": 162,
    "y": 147,
    "wires": [["62f0f292.9d0f0c"]]
}, {
    "id": "62f0f292.9d0f0c",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "f00fcb86.2de8f8",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "true",
    "complete": "true",
    "x": 344,
    "y": 147,
    "wires": []
}]
```

does someone have any ideas ?

Comment: According to your flow configuration above, it seems you have configured both of your websocket nodes (in and out) as client nodes (i.e. using `Type: Connect To`), which is not correct. Do you see other errors in your console? besides it seems that your config is missing the tab config which should be `{"type": "tab","id": "f00fcb86.2de8f8", "label": "Sheet 1"}`

Comment: Hi @Val no other error on console. I've try `connect To` both side or one `Listen` other `connect`, I've same error message. This apps should be more complexe but i need fix this probleme before to add other logic node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the json as a whole  is an array. In the first element of the array there is an object and within that is the wholemsg. Address as node-red json[0].wholemsg where "node-red json" is your variable name holding the message.

Comment: JSON is a tree not an array.