# where to find console in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, console, node-red

I can't find the console for Node-RED. 
Do I have to use Node-RED Runtime API's `RED.log()`? Some Node-RED frontends, like [FRED](https://fred.sensetecnic.com/), seem to have a console. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451159/node-red-and-web-socket) a console is mentioned. 
Is there a console accessible on the shell, or do I have to use the debug-Node?
Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: Where and how are you running Node-RED?

Answer (score 6):

Node-RED outputs data to the terminal it is started on.

So if you start it manually on the command line with `node-red` or `node red` it will print to the terminal.

If you've installed Node-RED as a service so it is launched at startup then it will depend on what platform you are on as to where the console log will end up. On Linux then there is a fair chance that it will end up in the journal and can be tailed with the following command:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u nodered -o cat
```

If you're running Node-RED on Bluemix then the you can see the console with the cf command line too:

```
cf logs <app-name>
```

or you can see it in the Bluemix web console.

As for sending data to this output then you have a few of options.

- The Debug node has an option to output to the console, this is useful when the msg object (or msg.payload) is too big to fit in the debug side bar.
- When writing your own nodes then you can use `RED.log`, This will add a time stamp and a node id to the output which can be useful when debugging.
- At a pinch you can use `console.log`, but this will just dump things to standard out with no formatting or time stamp

Comment: sudo journalctl -f -u nodered -o cat
worked like a charm for me on Raspberry Pi raspbian.

Comment: just to add. I encountered this when having the same situation. I run node-red on PM2. Later I found out that the command is `pm2 logs node-red`